ASP.NET Core 6 sending data from view to controller
I'm using ASP.NET Core 6, and I'm wondering if I can send data from one HTML view to the same controller but to two different methods using a single submit button? I'm using a single ASP form, and so far, I haven't found a way to do it without using JavaScript
Thanks
Sasa'
namespace ACS.Controllers
{
    public class MAWBController : Controller
    {
        private ProductContext _productContext;
    
        public MAWBController (ProductContext productContext)
        {
            _productContext = productContext;
        }
    
        public static List<Models.Shipment> listaMAWB = new List<Shipment>();
    
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult InsertMAWB()
        {
            return View();
        }
    
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult InsertMAWB(Shipment model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _productContext.Shipments.Add(model);
                _productContext.SaveChanges();
                    
                return RedirectToAction("Manipulacija");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    
        public IActionResult Manipulacija()
        {
            return View();
        }
    
        public IActionResult ShowListMAWB()
        {
            return View(listaMAWB);
        }
    
        public IActionResult IzracunTotalaPdv(decimal Manipulacija, decimal DgHandling,decimal PDV)
        {
            Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
    
            decimal UkupnoSPDV = shipment.UkupnoSPDV(Manipulacija, DgHandling, PDV);
    
            ViewBag.UkupnoSPDV = UkupnoSPDV;
    
            return View(shipment);
        }
    }
}

View:
@model ACS.Models.Shipment

<form asp-action="InsertMAWB" method="post">
    <label asp-for="ArrivalDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="ArrivalDate" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ArrivalDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </br>
        </br>
        <label asp-for="MAWB"></label>
        <input asp-for="MAWB" />
        <span asp-validation-for="MAWB" class="text-danger">
        </span>
    
        </br>
        </br>
    
        <label asp-for="GrossWeight"></label>
        <input asp-for="GrossWeight" />
        <span asp-validation-for="GrossWeight" class="text-danger">
        </span>
        
        </br>
        </br>
       
        <label asp-for="IsDG"></label>
        <input asp-for="IsDG" />
        <span asp-validation-for="IsDG" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       
        </br>
        </br>
    
        <div>
            <label for="Manipulacija">Manipulacija:</label>
            <input asp-for="Manipulacija" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Manipulacija" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="DgHandling">DgHandling:</label>
            <input asp-for="DgHandling" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DgHandling" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="PDV">PDV:</label>
            <input asp-for="PDV" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PDV" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    
        <button type="submit">Pošalji</button>
    </form>
</div>


 send data from one HTML view to the same controller but to two different methods using a single submit button -> Can when know when it will be sumbit to method one and when it will be sumbit to method two? If it requires a judgement, maybe we have to use js code to control it.

hi yes looks like that I need to use ajax to solve this
